# PostgreSQL: finding multiple columns that match a like clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I have a simple table:

```
column 1               column2               column3
 AA                     AAAA                    TT                
 AA                     BB                      EE
 AB                     C                       AABBCC 
 ABC                    XXX                     XYZ 
 AABB                   YYY                      A
```

now i tried to find all columns, that match e.g. 'AA%' resulting in:

```
column 1               column2               column3
 **AA**                **AAAA**                null                 
**AA**                  null                   null    
 null                   null                  *AABBCC* 
 null                   null                   null        
 **AABB**               null                   null
```

is that possible with one simple query?  my idea was to start with unions or temporay tables, but i can't get it to work. sorry for this simple beginner question and thanks in advance!

```sql
select d1.column1, d1.column2, d1.column3 from sample d1 where d1.column1 like 'AA%' 
   union 
      select d2.column1, d2.column2, d2.column3 from sample d2 where d2.column2 like 'AA%' 
         union 
            select d3.column1, d3.column2, d3.column3 from sample d3 where d3.column3 like 'AA%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use OR key-word as this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 
FROM sample 
WHERE column1 like 'AA%' 
OR column2 like 'AA%' 
OR column3 like 'AA%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You union query is also correct bt in case of simplicity i agree with Or query

Answer (score 0):

With PostgreSQL there is the ANY or ALL:

```
WHERE col LIKE ANY( subselect )
```

or

```
WHERE col LIKE ALL( subselect )
```

where the subselect returns exactly one column of data.